# org-export-select-tags and async export

Tags: org-mode, org-export

This question is a derivative of [Export to multiple files according to tags](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/35943/9245). I wish to export to different files, according to tags.

To achieve this goal, I wrote some lines of code :

```
(defun export (tagname)
   "Export to a file named tagname.pdf all the headlines tagged with tagname"
          (let ((org-export-select-tags (list tagname)) (async nil) (subtreep nil) (visible-only nil) (body-only nil) (ext-plist '())) 
               (org-export-to-file 'beamer (concat tagname ".tex") async subtreep visible-only body-only ext-plist (lambda (file) (org-latex-compile file))))
)

(export "s1")
(export "s2")
```

where `s1` and `s2` are the tags to generate files from.

This is working as expected and generates files "s1.pdf" and "s2.pdf" correctly.

However, when I change  `(async nil)` to  `(async t)`, the tag selection is not used anymore and two identical pdf files are generated, containing all headlines.

I would like to know if in async export, the variable `org-export-select-tags` is used and, if not, if it is possible to reduce the async export scope.

Comment: What is your emacs and org-mode version number?

Comment: @NiclasBörlin I use emacs 24.5.1 and org-mode 9.1.1 (my OS is Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: I don't have a direct answer to your question, but if you debug <code>org-export-to-file</code> (I used <code>edebug</code>) with <code>async</code> set to <code>t</code> or <code>nil</code>, respectively, you might see what <code>org-export-to-file</code> does differently.

Comment: I did the following in emacs to invoke edebug: 1. <code>C-h f org-export-to-file</code> to bring up the help for the function. 2. Click on the <code>ox.el</code> link in the help window to bring up the source code. 3. <code>M-x edebug-defun</code> to set a breakpoint at the beginning of the function. 4. Run code that invokes <code>org-export-to-file</code>.

Comment: @NiclasBörlin Thanks really for your detailled help and for the hints to understand how things work in org-export-to-file. I tried to understand the source code but it is very difficult for me since I learned lisp years ago. I will try the debug method you suggest, thanks again for all the details that will be very useful.