# Exporting to a Latex file only those sections which have a specific tag

Tags: org-mode

I have a long org mode document, and many sections are marked with several tags like say `:cricket:` , `:golf:`, `:tennis:`. Is it possible to export to a latex buffer only those sections  with the tag `:cricket:`?

Side question: is it possible to export to a separate Emacs *buffer* only those sections which have a particular tag attached to them. 
`C-c \` and typing the tag name, still shows the entire tree, (even if in a collapsed form) with the sections with matching tag names highlighted.

Comment: A possible answer to the first question is given in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/35943/9245 especially in EDIT2 section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add

```
 #+SELECT_TAGS: cricket
```

to your org file and export normally. If you modify SELECT_TAGS and want to reexport, be sure to `C-c C-c` on that line, so it will be reevaluated.

For the second part, you can use the above mechanism and do an export to org with `C-c C-e O O` (to a buffer) or `C-c C-e O o` to a file, then visit the new file (if you start with a file named cricket.org, the new file will be called cricket.org.org).